# Exoplayer with google IMA SDK

Tags: android, sdk, ads, exoplayer

I am trying to implement google ima sdk for exoplayer for preroll post roll ad rendering. Currently i am using the almost exact implementation of exoplayer as mentioned in github link https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo
Can anyone tell me how to proceed the integration using exoplayer and where should i implement my callbacks and the ad tag parameter handling so that i can make it work with exoplayer and not create a separate videoplayer implementation to handle ads. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The way to implement Google IMA with ExoPlayer is the same way as it's explained with the built in Android Media Player. The callbacks and events are going to be the same, instead calling the mediaPlayer.play() you need to call your Exo's wrapper play method.

Comment: Please explain or give any links

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this project from Google: [Google Media Framework](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android)

It is a video player with integrated IMA SDK and built on top of ExoPlayer (yeah).

Comment: Google media Framework does plays only prerol and midrol it fails to play post rol  ads. Did any one get this issue?